# Missing volume control in HTML5 player

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a problem with the HTML5 player. The volume button disappeared but the sound hasn't. What did I do wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<video id="vid1" loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls >
<source src="http://example.com/video/example-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I'm using: Chrome lastest version on Linux Ubuntu

I have no idea why that button disappeared. :/ With other videos everything works fine.

Comment: Either: 1. The MP4 file is corrupted, your OS's video player can auto-correct, but the chrome 67 HTML5 video player can't. The solution is to open/clean/re-encode/save the MP4 video.  Or 2: The place where you acquired your MP4 file has flags in it that indicate DRM viewing rights violations, as put there on purpose by content creators: latest versions of browsers retaliate with disobedience.  Or 3. Bugs in the browser or bugs in the operating system that the browser uses to decode MP4 video.  For more info, See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357612

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<video id="vid1" loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="">
   <source src="example-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: it didn't help :( It looks like strange issue
i checked console and i see 

"portal:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/portal' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video 'http://cdn.exampleg.com/video/example-video.mp4'. This content should also be served over HTTPS."

it can be a problem ?